# Indexing the term of unpublished entities

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a views of unpublished contents of content-type **X**, which has the Term Y.

It works fine with published content but a thing that I noticed is that if I unpublished a content that has a taxonomy term, in Views it loses the term associated with it, therefore I cannot filter my list based on taxonomy term anymore.

I also found [Taxonomy Entity Index](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index) module but it doesn't work at all.

Also [a related issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/962664)

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might encounter the same issue:

It looks like that it's a common issue in D7 and unfortunately going to be in D8, but hopefully the fix will be in core for D9.

Right now we have to use [TEI](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index) module as a workaround for D7 and D8.

If you are installing this module into an existing site, visit `admin/config/system/taxonomy-entity-index` to rebuild the Taxonomy Entity Index.

Also note that in Views there will be some new fields/filters to work with, for instance instead of `Content: Has taxonomy terms` in filters section of views, you should use `Taxonomy Entity Index: Has taxonomy terms on Nodes` and for exposing the taxonomy terms also you should use `Taxonomy Entity Index: Has taxonomy terms on Nodes` not the default `Content: Has taxonomy terms`.

Comment: Sohail wrote "Right now we have to use TEI module as a workaround for D7 and D8." But here: [TEI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index); I see that there is only drupal 7 and not drupal 8.

Comment: For D8, the TEI module isn't ready to use in prod.But @SeanC tips work.

Answer (score 3):

"Lookup published nodes with this taxonomy term" is such a common use-case that the Taxonomy module keeps a `taxonomy_index` table in the database to optimize for it.  This is what the `Content: has taxonomy term ID` views argument queries.  Unfortunately, it is only for published content.

In Drupal 8, there is a workaround. Taxonomy term fields are just a special case of Entity Reference fields, which have their own views argument handler, and do not partake of this special index.  So, if Content-type X has a 'Tags' field, you can build a view based around `Content: Tags (field_tags)`, and that will include unpublished content as you'd expect.

Comment: This is what helped me - to filter by a field in my content type that uses taxonomy term as entity reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 8 :

1. Apply the patch from this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/962664)
2. Clear cache : `drush cr`
3. Updade database : `drush updb`

It works for me.